# How to publish a database from SQL Server 2014 using .PublishSettings?

Tags: sql-server, azure, publish, sql-server-2014

I  have downloaded a publishing profile :

```
mysite.azurewebsites.net.PublishSettings
```

I used

> Deploy Database to a Window Azure...

from SQL Server 2014 and publish a database, but I am getting the exception as below :

> Failed to import
>   C:\Users\thuat.nguyen\Downloads\mysite.azurewebsites.net.PublishSettings
>   publish settings profile.  (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)
>
> was not expected. (Microsoft.GeneratedCode)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPublishData.Read5_PublishData()

How I can fix this ?

Comment: As I understand it, the .publishSettings file should be in XML format -- by the looks of the error, you may have something else. Does the file actually *look* right if you open in in a text editor?

Comment: including mysite.azurewebsites.net.PublishSettings code could helps a lot

Comment: it is XML file but the problem is why expecting [<publishData xmlns=''> was not expected.] ?